# Mongoose find not executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's what I've got in a file called Zone.js,

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('debug', true);

var zoneSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, default: '', required: true},
    timestamp: {type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true},
    zipCodes: {type: [String], default: [], required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Zone', zoneSchema);
```

And then here's what I've got in a file called zoneController.js,

```
var Zone = require('../models/Zone');

module.exports = {
    find: function(params, callback){
        console.log('Finding zone');
        Zone.find(params, function(err, zones){
            console.log('Got results');
            if (err){
                callback(err, null);
                return;
            }
            callback(null, zones);
        });
    }
}
```

And then, I have,

```
ZoneController = require('../controllers/zoneController');
ZoneController.find({}, function(err, results){
            console.log('Zone results received');
}
```

The problem is that the .find() method doesn't give me anything. I get 'Finding zone' in my console, but absolutely nothing after that.

My folder structure is correct and I am referencing the correct files.

Comment: The `err` parameter is there for a reason. Check if it contains any result. Beside that, are you connecting to the DB at all?

Comment: @qqilihq Yes, I'm connecting to the database

Comment: @qqilihq As for the error, I can't log it because the find() method never gets executed

Comment: About the error, makes sense! Still it sounds to me that you're not connected to the DB at the point where you're trying to query. Are you sure that `mongoose.connect` has been called when you call `find`?

Comment: See here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering -- "This buffering is convenient, but also a common source of confusion. Mongoose will not throw any errors by default if you use a model without connecting."

Comment: And? Any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

try this, I think that you must to return your find method in your controller.
let me know if it work.

```js
module.exports = {
    return {
        find: function(params, callback) {
            console.log('Finding zone');
            Zone.find(params, function(err, zones) {
                console.log('Got results');
                if (err) {
                    callback(err, null);
                    return;
                }
                callback(null, zones);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a .find example for Tweet model in one of my old projects.

```
Tweet.find({}).sort({date: -1}).populate('_creator').exec((err, tweets) => {
        res.render('tweet-all', {title: `All Tweets`, tweets: tweets});
});
```

I think you must use .exec() in Model.

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations did my answer help you out? If so, please vote it up and mark it as correct answer :)